# Lowpoly model painted with a color palette has wrong colors when imported into Unreal Engine!

Tags: materials, uv, color, unreal-engine

EDIT: SOLVED. The issue was with my color palette. I don't know why but the 16x16 size was causing problems (I assume). Switching to a 512x512 palette fixed the color issues!

I am fairly new to Blender and have been modeling some simple lowpoly characters. I "texture" them using a color palette and UV mapping. However, when I import them into UE4, their colors change. I cannot figure out why this happens, and I'd appreciate support on this matter!

My character(s) in Blender:
[image]

and when imported into UE4:
[image]

As I stated above, I did the coloring in Blender using a 256 color palette, and my material looks like this:
[image]

And the material in UE4:
[image]

Finally my FBX export settings:

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE! What format do you export from Blender that you import into UE4? Can you please include this info in your post.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Hi! Thank you :) I am exporting as FBX, I will update the post with my export settings for further clarification.

Comment: Try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEP34CbPWUo)  quick tutorial. - Watch the export setting he uses near the end...

Comment: @JohnEason tried it, thanks! sadly no difference though... I think maybe it has to do with the texture interpolation setting on the image texture node in Blender..?